# How to convert non-string variable to string in Less?

Tags: svg, less

I have a mixin like the below which gives a `background-image: <white version of black svg image>`;

```
.foo(@img-url) {
    @encoded-black: escape("#000000");
    @encoded-white: escape("#ffffff");
    @data-uri: data-uri("image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8", "@{img-url}");
    @new-uri: replace("@{data-uri}", "@{encoded-black}", "@{encoded-white}");
    background-image:e(@new-uri);
}
```

I want to use it as follows:

```
.myClass {
    .foo(url('../../myImg.svg'));
}
```

But it only works when used as follows:

```
.myClass {
    .foo('../../myImg.svg');
}
```

I want to accept the param with the url part and just chop off the 'url(' and ')' using replace method but it seems there is no way to convert the url param into a string, at least not that I have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually no need to convert the `url()` parameter into a string separately. You can directly do it within the `replace()` function itself.

In the below code, the `"@{img-url}"` would make the input value as a string and then using the regex the `url()` can be stripped off. The stripping must be done before using the `data-uri()` function and the stripped value should be passed as input to it because the [`data-uri()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-data-uri) function needs only a path and it need not (or should not) be in the `url()` format.

```css
.foo(@img-url) {
  @encoded-black: escape("#000000");
  @encoded-white: escape("#ffffff");
  @img-url-new: replace("@{img-url}", "url\('(.+)'\)", '$1');
  @data-uri: data-uri("image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8", '@{img-url-new}');
  @new-uri: replace("@{data-uri}", "@{encoded-black}", "@{encoded-white}");
  background-image: e(@new-uri);
}
.myClass {
  .foo(url('../../myImg.svg'));
}
```

When the above code is compiled by placing a dummy SVG file in the required folder, it produces the following CSS: (this was compiled with `--no-ie-compat`)

```css
.myClass {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D'0%200%20100%20100'%3E%0D%0A%09%3Ccircle%20cx%3D'0'%20cy%3D'0'%20r%3D'50'%20stroke%3D%22%23ffffff%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fsvg%3E");
}
```

Here is the dummy SVG file's content just for reference:

```xml
<svg viewBox='0 0 100 100'>
  <circle cx='0' cy='0' r='50' stroke="#000000"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Btw., I cannot test `lessc` right now (and `data-uri` is not quite supported in all online comilers), but have you tried if `data-uri` supports `url()` as its path arg? (note not `"url()"` (as in the Q above) which is not valid, but normal `url()`). It's not documented, but looking at source code I suspect it could - and if it is - then no `replace` would be necessary at all - since one would need to use `@img-url` as the function arg (and never `"@{img-url}"`yet again because `"url(...)"` is not valid url :).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Actually I did and this - `@data-uri: data-uri("image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8", @img-url);` did not work. *Edit:* Error message was "SyntaxError: error evaluating function `data-uri`: Object [object Object] has no method 'indexOf' in [File Path]".

Comment: OK, then I suppose this should be raised as an issue, because I see no excuses for the function to not support `url()` path values.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Not using regex with the replacement was where I went wrong.